# Nest n loops for any n in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

So, let's say I have an arbitrarily long list of numbers. I'd like to get a list of every number in that list multiplied by every number in that list. I'd do that by nesting `for` loops like this:

```
for x in numbers:
    for y in numbers:
        print(x*y)
```

Now if I'd like to multiply every number in that list times every number in that list times every number in that list *again*, I'd do this:

```
for x in numbers:
    for y in numbers:
        for z in numbers:
            print(x*y*z)
```

My issue is that I'm searching a graph for a subgraph, and I need to allow for arbitrarily large subgraphs. To do this I have to construct every subgraph with *n* edges from the edges in the main graph - and I have to allow for arbitrary values of *n*. How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with an iterative product computing function (I favor `reduce(mul, ...)`). If you need `n`-way products (in both senses of the word "product"):

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

for numset in itertools.product(numbers, repeat=n):
    print(reduce(mul, numset))
```

The above is simple, but it will needlessly recompute partial products when the set of values is large and `n >= 3`. A recursive function could be used to avoid that:

```
def compute_products(numbers, repeat):
    if repeat == 1:
        yield from numbers
        return
    numbers = tuple(numbers)  # Only needed if you want to handle iterator/generator inputs
    for prod in compute_products(numbers, repeat-1):
        yield from (prod * x for x in numbers)

for prod in compute_products(numbers, n):
    print(prod)
```

Comment: FYI, in Py2, the `functools` import for `reduce` isn't necessary, but `Py3` moved `reduce` out of the built-in namespace.

Comment: Of course the multiplication example was just an example, but I get the idea.

Comment: you should measure the time performance to check whether the recursive solution is actually slower for a given type of input.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I did some timing tests, and it's definitely not cut and dry. The recursive solution *will* be slower for many inputs, simply because it's executing more Python byte code along with incurring the cost of setting up Python stack frames. For the simple case addressed here, the `itertools.product` solution moves 99% of the work to the C layer (in CPython anyway; PyPy and others don't benefit from stuff like this), which gives it a lower fixed multiplier on compute cost, even if the big-O cost is higher.

Comment: What are the big-O costs here?

Comment: If I'm calculating correctly, the `product`+`reduce` version is performing `len(numbers)**n * (n-1)` multiplications. The recursive solution should be doing only `len(numbers) ** n` multiplications (no `n-1` multiplier). Obviously, `n` as the exponential term is a far bigger growth factor than its effect as an additional multiplier, but it adds up (particularly if you're working with big numbers where multiplication is expensive).

Answer (score 0):

I think a recursive function of some kind would probably help you. This is just untested pseudocode typed into the Stack Overflow editor, so beware of using this verbatim, but something like this:

```
def one_dimension(numbers, n):
    if (n < 1):
        return
    for num in numbers:
        for next_num in one_dimension(numbers, n-1):
            yield num*next_num
```

The basic idea is that each "level" of the function calls the next one, and then deals with what the next one produces. I don't know how familiar you are with Python's `yield` keyword, but if you know what it does, then you should be able to adapt the code above.

**Update:** Or just use `itertools.product` like ShadowRanger suggested in his answer; that's probably a better solution to your problem.